# Solution of $xy'+y+x^3y^3e^{-x^2}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, gaussian-integral

Consider the following ode :

$$xy'+y+x^3y^3e^{-x^2}=0$$

I solved it as a Bernoulli equation and found :

$y(x)= \frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{2x^2 \int e^{-x^2}}dx}$

I know I can write $\int e^{-x^2}dx$ using the error function(this is the solution given by Mathematica), but I was wondering if there is another way to write it. I thought about writing the Taylor series of $e^{-x^2}$ but I am not sure if I can swap the integral and the summation in order to evaluate the integral on this situation(indefinite integral).
So my question is :

Is there another way to write $y(x)$ or is the error function the only option?

Comment: If there was a way to write $y(x)$ in terms of elementary functions it would mean that $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$ is elementary which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$xy'+y+y^3x^3e^{-x^2}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x\frac{y'}{y^3}+\frac{1}{y^2}+x^3e^{-x^2}=0$$
And this looks a bit like the Cauchy-Euler equation, maybe try a substitution for $y$?

Comment: You get there faster if you observe that $xy'+y=(xy)'$, as the resulting equation is separable.

Comment: @LutzLehmann ahh smart, I didn't see that :)